# Boost regex difficulties

Tags: regex, boost

I am trying to parse some text using boost. i have looked at the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) on the official site but it doesn't seem to be working. I have written my own example; it doesn't enter the while loop at all.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string s;
    string::const_iterator st, en;
    s = "int_node:0 int_node:1 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:2 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:3 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:4 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:5 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:6 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1\n"
       "int_node:0 int_node:7 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1";

    st = s.begin();
    en = s.end();
    boost::regex expression("int_node:([0-9]+) int_node:([0-9]+)"
                            " link_latency:([0-9]+) bw_multiplier:([0-9]+)"
                            " link_weight:([0-9]+) long_range:([0-9]+)"
                        " no_of_vcs:([0-9]+)");

    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;


    boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;

    while(boost::regex_search(st, en, what, expression, flags))
    {
      st = what[0].second;
          flags |= boost::match_prev_avail;
          flags |= boost::match_not_bob;

      cout << what[1] << " " << what[2] << " " << what[3] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to parse a file that looks like this:

```
int_node:0 int_node:1 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1
int_node:0 int_node:2 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1
int_node:0 int_node:3 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1
int_node:0 int_node:4 link_latency:1 bw_multiplier:16 link_weight:1
```

and retrieve the integer values for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression has 7 elements but each line you're searching only has 5.

You could try one of two options.  Either reduce the number of elements to only 5

```
    boost::regex expression("int_node:([0-9]+) int_node:([0-9]+) link_latency:([0-9]+) bw_multiplier:([0-9]+) link_weight:([0-9]+)");
```

or, if there will be some lines that might have the last two elements (and you want to reference them), use a positive look-ahead assertion like this:

```
    boost::regex expression("int_node:([0-9]+) int_node:([0-9]+) link_latency:([0-9]+) bw_multiplier:([0-9]+) link_weight:([0-9]+)(?= long_range:([0-9]+) no_of_vcs:([0-9]+))?");
```

If you're not familiar with regex, the `(?:REGEX)?` will say that the last two elements are optional, and the `?:` at the beginning means this particular grouping doesn't count.  If there is a value in the 6th column (long_range), then `what[6]` will contain the long_range value, otherwise it will be blank.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't read the expression entirely(overlooked the last part).

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression has two more fields than your strings have: `long_range` and `no_of_vcs`. Since these aren't in the strings, the regex doesn't match the strings.

By the way, I edited your question to split the strings across lines. In C++, adjacent string literals are concatenated: `"a" "b"` is equivalent to `"ab"`. By using this syntax, and thereby eliminating horizontal scrolling, it's easier to see what's going on. I'm pretty sure you would have noticed the discrepancy if you had written it that way to begin with.